# Detect percent on screen of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I'm trying to detect what % of the element can be seen on the current window.

For example, if the user can only see half the element, return 50. If the user can see the whole element, return 100.

Here's my code so far:

```
function getPercentOnScreen() {
    var $window = $(window),
        viewport_top = $window.scrollTop(),
        viewport_height = $window.height(),
        viewport_bottom = viewport_top + viewport_height,
        $elem = $(this),
        top = $elem.offset().top,
        height = $elem.height(),
        bottom = top + height;

    return (bottom - viewport_top) / height * 100;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help me out in achieveing this I seem to be spinning gears.

Comment: Where is the orginal size in pixels? you Will need that to start with so set a width and height variable first to indicate the size, then try one of the answers below and do some math. eg if your elements size is 200px by 200px, and new size is 150px by 75px the answer is (150 + 75) / (200 + 200) * 100 = 56.25%

Answer (score 1):

What you want to get is the amount of pixels that the element extends past the top and bottom of the viewport. Then you can just subtract it from the total height and divide by that height to get the percentage onscreen.

```
var px_below = Math.max(bottom - viewport_bottom, 0);
var px_above = Math.max(viewport_top - top, 0);
var percent = (height - px_below - px_above) / height;
return percent;
```

One thing to note is that jQuery's height method won't include padding. You probably want to use `.outerHeight` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$elem = $(this)`assignment seems wrong, here function scoping means `this` refers to the function you're in (ala ~ the function getPercentOnScreen), try referencing by `$elem = $('#yourElementId')`instead.

Comment: This depends on how the function is called.  If this is used as an event handler, `this` will be the element.

Comment: @JamesMontagne good catch on making that distinction, s'pose the same would hold true if it extends jquery s.t. it's called using `$(element).getPercentOnScreen()`

Answer (score -1):

if you only want to calculate percent of element then just do this

```
function getPercentOnScreen(elem) {
    $docHeight = $(document).height();
    $elemHeight  = $(elem).height();

    return ($elemHeight/$docHeight)* 100;
}
```